# Connect to EC2 server through AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a shell script on my EC2 server and I want to trigger the same from AWS lambda function. Can anyone suggest how I can access the file in my lambda function. There is no connectivity issue between lambda and EC2.

I generated the private key with Putty gen and kept it in s3 bucket and using same key to connect(With this private key able to connect through putty).I have piece of code like this.

```
var driver, ssh;
driver = require('node-ssh');
ssh = new driver();
exports.handle = function(error, ctx, cb) {
ssh = new driver({
          host: 'EC2 public ip',
          username: 'uname',
          privateKey : 'url of s3/privatekey.ppk'
        });
ssh.connect().then(function() {
    console.log('connected')
        },function(error) {
            console.log(error);

        });
 }
```

First I am trying to see if I can connect to my EC2 server and then I can run the shell script through ssh client. But connection is not happening.Getting below error.

```
{
"errorMessage": "config.host must be a valid string",
"errorType": "Error",
"stackTrace": [
"Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/node-ssh/lib/helpers.js:15:13)",
"next (native)",
"step (/var/task/node_modules/node-ssh/lib/helpers.js:69:191)",
"/var/task/node_modules/node-ssh/lib/helpers.js:69:437",
"Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/node-ssh/lib/helpers.js:69:99)",
"Object.normalizeConfig (/var/task/node_modules/node-  ssh/lib/helpers.js:42:17)",
"/var/task/node_modules/node-ssh/lib/index.js:53:25",
"SSH.connect (/var/task/node_modules/node-ssh/lib/index.js:52:14)",
"exports.handle (/var/task/index.js:13:7)"
]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you had the file in S3 and access it there from EC2 and Lambda?

Comment: Thanks for reply Tom. But I have a situation. I have a jar file on my EC2 and this shell script executes that jar. Now I want to run this shell script by my lambda function. It is a part of my application which is completely based on AWS step function. So I don't see any option to keep the shell script in s3 as it need to run the jar file on EC2.

Comment: Why can't you run it all in Lambda? You can include jar files with your Lambda code.

Answer (score 2):

You would need something running on your EC2 instance to "receive" the request.

Some options:

- Run a web server and call it from the Lambda function, or
- Use the [EC2 Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/) which uses an agent on the EC2 instance and can be called via the AWS API, or
- Have the Lambda function push a message into an Amazon SQS queue and have the instance continually poll the queue

It would be much simpler if you could simply run the code in your Lambda function instead.

Comment: My code is calling some other applications SOAP services whose response time is more than 5 minutes so I cant directly write the code in lambda. Other thing is it is an AWS step function activity and cant be written as a web application so I wrote the code in java main method. Again it cant run continuously with the EC2 run command due to readTimeout constraint in step function.

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer to this question. Hope it will help.

```
 package com.wb.mars.ingest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.wb.mars.ingest.CustomEventInput;
import com.wb.mars.ingest.CustomEventOutput;


public class EC2ConnectLambda implements RequestHandler<CustomEventInput,CustomEventOutput> {

    public CustomEventOutput handleRequest(CustomEventInput input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
         System.out.println("test");
    try {

        String command1 = "cd /home/ec2-user/mydir; ./runjar.sh";


        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        String user = "ec2-user";

        String host = "*.*.*.*";
        int port = 22;

        //File file = new File( EC2ConnectLambda.class.getResource( "/Linux_EC2.pem" ).toURI() );
        File file = new File( EC2ConnectLambda.class.getResource( "/mykey.pem" ).toURI() );

        String privateKeyabsolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyabsolutePath);
        System.out.println("identity added ");

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        System.out.println("session created.");

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();
        System.out.println("session connected.....");

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
        OutputStream o = channel.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(o);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);

        channel.connect();

        // 4 - Clean up
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new CustomEventOutput("lambdaInvoked");
}
```

}